# Finding where my proof that if $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite matrices, then $AB$ is positive-definite is wrong.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products, positive-definite

I know the claim is wrong, yet I found an interesting 'proof' that shows the claim is right, and I haven't been able to show why it's wrong.

It goes as follows:

I'll use the claim that $\langle Ax, y \rangle$ is inner product iff A is positive-definite.

Since, A and B are positive-definite, then $\langle Ax, y \rangle$, $\langle Bx, y \rangle$ are inner products.

From here, we can deduce that $\langle ABx, y \rangle = \langle Bx, y \rangle_{A} = \langle x, y \rangle_{AB}$, and from the claim above we get that $AB$ is positive-definite.

What is wrong in the proof?

Comment: The more common notation is to write $\langle Ax, y\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle_A$ and $\langle Bx, y \rangle = \langle x,y\rangle_B$, rather than switching the style of brackets. (So we'd write $\langle ABx, y\rangle = \langle Bx, y\rangle_A$, and the mistake is that $\langle Bx,y\rangle_A$ is not necessarily an inner product.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov But since B is positive-definite, doesn't that imply that $\langle Bx, y \rangle_{A}$ is an inner product by the claim used above?

Comment: No, because $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_A$ is not the standard inner product, and the positive-definiteness of $B$ only applies to the standard inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in

> From here, $\color{red}{\text{we can deduce that}}$ $\langle ABx, y \rangle = (Bx, y) = \{x, y\}$, where $\{x, y\}$ $\color{red}{\text{is an inner product}}$, and from the claim above we get that $AB$ is positive-definite.

Avoiding notation, you are saying that $(Ax)^Ty$ and $(Bx)^Ty$ being inner products (which is correct) implies that $(ABx)^Ty$ is also an inner product. Why is that? It would certainly imply that $AB$ is positive definite, but you have to show that $(ABx)^Ty$ is also an inner product (which is false in general).

For example, $A=B=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ define the inner product $(Ax)^Ty=(Bx)^Ty$ since $A$ is positive definite as $$x^T A x=2x_1^2+3x_1x_2+2x_2^2=\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)+\frac{3}{2}(x_1+x_2)^2>0\text{ whenever }x\neq0$$
but $AB=A^2=4\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ doesn't define an inner product since, taking $x=\binom{1}{-1}$, you get $(A^2x)^Tx=-4<0$.

Comment: Or perhaps easier: $\;A^2\;$ isn't even symmetrix and thus cannot be poisitive definite. Symmetry isn't in general kept by matrix multiplication, unless the matrices commute.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite get what you are saying. Are you saying that every positive definite matrix is symmetric? If that's the case, $A$ isn't symmetric either but it is positive definite.

Comment: True. The definition of "positive definite", in particular for inner products, assumes almost always from the beginning that the matrix is symmetric. True, you can talk of "positive matrix" without requiring symmetry, but then we run into problems: your example of $\;A\;$ does *not* define an inner product since it isn't symmetrix, and you can check this with $$\;x=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\end{pmatrix}\,,\,\,y=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}\;$$ where we get $\;x^tAy\neq y^tAx\;$ ....

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing "inner product" with "inner product space". Presumably the correct claim is that if we take the set $\Bbb R^n$ and define on it the two-variable function $f(x,y)=\langle Ax,y \rangle$, then $f(x,y)$ is an inner product (which then makes $(\Bbb R^n,f)$ into an inner product space) if and only if $A$ is positive definite.

The statement definitely doesn't say that $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R^n$. And the proposed equality $\langle Bx,y\rangle=\{x,y\}$ doesn't scan: $\langle Bx,y\rangle$ is a number, while $\{x,y\}$ is a set.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, I'm learning the subject in a different language, so it's certain I'll be wrong now and then. As for your comment, I think I didn't explain my notations very well. I meant that $\langle Ax, y \rangle = (x, y) $, where $(x, y)$ is just a notation of an inner product, as well as $\{x, y\}$.

Comment: To convince yourself that $A$ being positive definite doesn't imply that $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$, consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ for example.

Comment: I think @Yoxbox isn't claiming that $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$  when  $A$ is positive definite but that $\langle Ax,y\rangle$ is another inner product (which is true). From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix), "In other words, a matrix is positive-definite if and only if it defines an inner product."

Comment: Ok, but then that inaccurate use of the equals sign is precisely what leads to the fallacy in the OP.

Comment: Exactly where in the OP does it say that $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$? It's a genuine question since I can only find the equality $\langle ABx,y\rangle = (Bx,y)=\{x,y\}$ which is different from $\langle ABx,y\rangle = \langle Bx,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$. @Yoxbox uses $(x,y)$ and $\{x,y\}$ to denote other inner products where, in fact, $\{x,y\}$ isn't an inner product. The OP isn't claiming $\langle ABx,y\rangle = \langle Bx,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: After rereading (for the severalth time) and peering at the chosen brackets under a microscope, I finally understand the point you're making. But that just makes me reaffirm my critique: the use of the equals sign between things that are not intended to be equal is misleading the OP so much that the notation is literally creating mathematical falsehoods in their mind.